How to calculate magnetic field strength of a solenoid from a certain distance?
Say we have a solenoid meant for creating large electromagnetic fields . If this electromagnet had an amperage of 150 amperes, 1100 turns, a length of 10 centimetres, iron core with a permeability of 1000, and a horseshoe shape. What I am having trouble with is finding how strong this field will be at a distance. So how strong would this electromagnet be from a distance of 5 meters?

I googled all the units that I thinker matter so if I missed any please tell me.
